# cant load json data from .json file

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, jakarta-ee

i am trying to load json object from a file .. but it always go to the error message

```
<html>

   <head>
      <title>The jQuery Example</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript"
         src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#driver").click(function(event){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'file.json',
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    error: function(data){
                        $('#stage').html("error");
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#stage').html("ay 7aga");
                        }
                    });
            });
         });
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>

      <p>Click on the button to load result.html file:</p>

      <div id = "stage">
         STAGE
      </div>

      <input type = "button" id = "driver" value = "Load Data" />

   </body>

</html>
```

And my `file.json`

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

And here is the file location

[image]

any suggestions to go to the success message ??
it says `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

please help i am beginner
any suggestions please .. thanks in advance

Comment: It looks to me that you have placed your json file in the wrong location. I assume that the folder where you have index.html is your web-root. So that is where your json file needs to be. Assuming a static file server.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your file location, is it correctly placed in your machine.

```
          $.ajax({
                    url: './file.json', //Check this file location.
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    error: function(data){
                        $('#stage').html("error");
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#stage').html("ay 7aga");
                        }
                    });
            });
```

If it is correctly located then what server your using??
If it is IIS add MIME type as JSON in the server

Comment: i will make a screen shot of it now

Answer (score 0):

Try using url:'../file.json' that is, one level up reference to the json file